# How to implement tool-tip on Stacked bar chart in Power BI

Tags: tooltip, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a Stacked bar chart that displays Tasks by UserName.
So each user can have:
Closed Tasks - black color
Overdue Tasks - red color 
Open Tasks - green color

[image]

How can I use a tool-tip so when I drag my mouse on any of tasks I want to see how many of those task are particular type.

[image]

For example, if I am interested in user Alison Petrarca, if I point my mouse on a green color (where value is 24) I want to see that there is  8 of them are "Audits" type; 9 of them are "Follow-up" type; 6 of them are "Pending Cancellation" type etc.

Same if I point my mouse on a red color (where value is 6) I want to see what types of tasks contain those 6.

Is it possible to achieve that?

So far I created a couple of measures for Audit type for Open and Overdue tasks:

```
AuditsOpen = CALCULATE(SUM(TotalCounts[OpenTasks]), TotalCounts[Type]= "Audits")
AuditsOpen = CALCULATE(SUM(TotalCounts[OpenTasks]), TotalCounts[Type]= "Audits")
```

But then, even if I point mouse only on green (Open Tasks) I still see Audits for open tasks and audits for Closed tasks.
But I only want to see for open tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshaping your data will make this fairly simple. Take your `TotalCounts` table and unpivot the `ClosedTasks`, `OverdueTasks`, and `OpenTasks` columns in the query editor so that it looks like this:

```
AssignedTo       | Type   | Status       | Tasks
-----------------|--------|--------------|-------
Allison Petrarca | Audits | ClosedTasks  | 6
Allison Petrarca | Audits | OverdueTasks | 3
Allison Petrarca | Audits | OpenTasks    | 8
Allison Petrarca | Claims | ClosedTasks  | 4
Allison Petrarca | Claims | OverdueTasks | 0
Allison Petrarca | Claims | OpenTasks    | 0
... (etc.) ...
```

Then you can put `AssignedTo` on your Axis, `Status` as your Legend, and `Tasks` as your Value. Then you'll create a measure for each `Type` you want on the tooltip. I.e.

```
Audits = CALCULATE(SUM(TotalCounts[Tasks]), TotalCounts[Type]="Audits")
Claims = CALCULATE(SUM(TotalCounts[Tasks]), TotalCounts[Type]="Claim")
... (etc.) ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Always great answers!